# How to suppress warnings in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

In a development environment, using docker-compose with a compose file made for Docker Swarm, e.g.:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  some-service:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    configs:
      - source: some-config
        target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
configs:
  some-config:
    external: true
```

there's always a warning like:

```
WARNING: Some services (some-service) use the 'configs' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'configs' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
```

This main file is for production, and is combined with other compose file(s), adding bind mounts and debug configuration, but don't know how to remove the 'configs' key.

Is there a way to suppress this warning or remove the 'configs' key with a compose file override?

Comment: Can you share your compose file?

Answer (score 1):

The `configs` key is a multi-value option and canno't be overriden. An override file will concatenate its own values to the existing ones.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration

I suggest to keep the Swarm specific keys in a separate dedicated `docker-compose` file and combine it with the others when needed.

Comment: I would like to avoid that. I prefer to facilitate production deployment by having a single compose file, and then multiple files for different development/debug scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose now has a log-level flag.

For example `docker-compose --log-level ERROR run --rm ...`.
This will suppress the warnings, but you will still see the container output.

Comment: This may work with docker-compose but seemingly not with the compose plugin (ie., "docker compose".

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the "cleanest" solution but could help you limit the "verbosity" of the `docker compose` output on production servers.
Here is for example how you can mute warning logs with when running a `docker compose ps`:

```
docker compose ps -q 2>&1 | grep -Pv "level=warning msg="
```

You have three "hacks" that would help you get rid of unwanted warning logs:

- `-q`: whenever possible to associate it with the docker compose command.
- `2>&1` by including `2>&1`, we ensure that the `grep` command filters both the regular output and the warning messages coming from the `stderr` output. Beware without this you will keep getting the unwanted lines in the output as they are not arraiving at the `grep` piped command.
- `grep -Pv "level=warning msg="`. As the `grep` documentation states:

> -v
>
> --invert-match
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX.)